SFMC | Create SFTP User | Impact on Existing SFTP based automations
Can anyone explain this warning! which appears while creating a new SFTP User.
Especially what does this 'Default Location' points to?


New FTP Accounts in SFMC have had different characteristics over the years. Currently, you have the ability to create up to 10 FTP users per business unit yourself (without SF Support assistance). It's good to remember that for every business unit account, one FTP server location is allocated for file storage.
Historically, you were supposed to ask SF Support to create a new FTP account with the specific FTP server location allocated and this location could have been different for different accounts. For example, once a request was made to update the Child Business Unit FTP path to point to the parent business unit, SF Support would manually update it on the backend. However, if a new FTP user was later created within the child business unit, the FTP path would automatically revert to the child business unit's FTP location.
Example of the standard FTP Path for MID: 222222222 looks like this: \ftp\222222222
Considering, that you never ever asked SF Support to change this path on your Business Unit, then there will not be any impact to your Automations or Imports. However, if you asked SF Support to change this path for some users, then you should ask them for assistance when creating a new FTP Account. Otherwise, it may happen that your existing imports or Automations will stop working due to the FTP server location path change back to the standard one.
